# Notification to a Javascript variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, notifications, event-handling, dom-events

I have a common event handler for changing of the values for a dynamically created Property Browser (Key value pair of property Name and Property Value). Where I am creating the controls of the KVP depending upon the type of the Property.

```
//Property Object
function PropertyValue(
    PropertyName, 
    PropertyValue, 
    PropertyType, 
    PropertyValueList
) {
    this.PropertyName = PropertyName;
    this.PropertyValue = PropertyValue;
    this.PropertyType = PropertyType;
    this.PropertyValueList = PropertyValueList;
}

//List of Objects for the Property Browser.
var propertyList = [];
```

Now I am creating the control type like (ComboBox,ColorPicker,CheckBox,TextBox) depending on the **PropertyType** value. I am having a common event to get the notification.

```
function OnUpdate(event) {
    var element = event.target;
    UpdateProperty(element.id);
    alert(element.id  + ":" +element.value);
}
```

This property values are for a chart control which is drawn on a canvas and is redrawn on each 250 milliseconds (Custom Redraw function called in `SetInter`). I want the value change to be updated as soon as I change any property value in the property browser.
I don't want to update the value in an array and then iterate through the loop to get the updated value.

Answer (score 0):

```
            window.PropertyType.addEventListener('stateChange', function() {
            if (PropertyType= //value or range or values) {
                   //execute change
            }
            else (PropertyType= //value or range or values) {  
                   //execute change
            }
```

I dont think i fully understand the problem but if there are only so many options for the change of state could a listener that iterated through an ifelse loop do the trick?